# Code for gensim Word2vec as an HTTP service 'KeyedVectors' Attribute error

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I am using the [w2v_server_googlenews](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/w2v_server_googlenews) code from the word2vec HTTP server running at https://rare-technologies.com/word2vec-tutorial/#bonus_app. I changed the loaded file to a file of vectors trained with the original C version of word2vec. I load the file with

```
gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(fname, binary=True)
```

and it seems to load without problems. But when I test the HTTP service with, let's say

```
curl 'http://127.0.0.1/most_similar?positive%5B%5D=woman&positive%5B%5D=king&negative%5B%5D=man'
```

I got an empty result with only the execution time.

```
{"taken": 0.0003361701965332031, "similars": [], "success": 1}
```

I put a `traceback.print_exc()` on the except part of the related method, which is in this case `def most_similar(self, *args, **kwargs):` and I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./w2v_server.py", line 114, in most_similar
    topn=5)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py", line 304, in most_similar
    self.init_sims()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py", line 817, in init_sims
    self.syn0norm = (self.syn0 / sqrt((self.syn0 ** 2).sum(-1))[..., newaxis]).astype(REAL)
AttributeError: 'KeyedVectors' object has no attribute 'syn0'
```

Any idea on why this might happens?

Note: I use python 2.7 and I installed gensim using pip, which gave me gensim 2.1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI that demo code was baed on gensim 0.12.3 (from 2015, as listed in its `requirements.txt`), and would need updating to work with the latest gensim.

It might be sufficient to add a line to `w2v_server.py` at line 70 (just after the `load_word2vec_format()`), to force the creation of the needed `syn0norm` property (which in older gensims was auto-created on load), before deleting the raw `syn0` values. Specifically:

```
self.model.init_sims(replace=True)
```

(You would leave out the `replace=True` if you were going to be doing operations other than `most_similar()`, that might require raw vectors.)

If this works to fix the problem for you, a pull-request to the [w2v_server_googlenews](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/w2v_server_googlenews) repo would be favorably received!